# How to best pass URL query params from hapi to Mongoose

Tags: mongoose, hapi.js

I have a hapi server, connecting to mongodb via mongoose, and a simple model, e.g. User.

I'd like to enable filtering of users, e.g.

```
User.find(req.query, function () {...});
```

where `req.query` would be parsed from URL, and be something like:

```
{count: {$gt: 10, $lt: 100}}
```

Can anyone suggest which combination of query parser library and URL param syntax to use, if there is anything readily available at all?

This seems like it should be a somewhat common problem, but I've been unable to find existing solutions...

EDIT:

Of course, I'd like a generic solution, and avoid manually parsing a fixed set of params for every model.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Joi](https://github.com/hapijs/joi) to validate query parameters. It integrates very easily with Hapi. And there's no need to add any special querystring parsing. Parameters are available on the `request.query` object. You can access [path parameters](http://hapijs.com/tutorials/routing#path) through the `request.params` object.

When you're using Joi, if any of the parameter checks fail, an error response will be returned before the route handler function is ever called. Simple example:

```
var User = require('./UserModel');
var joi = require('joi');

var getUsersRoute = {
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/users/{user_id?}',
    config: {
        validate: {
            params: {
                user_id: joi.number().optional().default(null)
            },
            query: {
                count: joi.number().min(10)
            }
        }
    },
    handler: function(request, reply) {
        if(request.params.user_id){
            /* do something with the id if you want to */
        }

        User.find(request.query, function(results) {
            reply(results);
        });

    }
};
```

Also check out the page on [Validation](http://hapijs.com/tutorials/validation#validation). It's a pretty good breakdown of how it it all works.

Answer (score -1):

You could just do something like this:

```
var url = require('url');

function(req,res){

  //parse query params using node url module
  //url is a core node module, no npm install needed
  var params = url.parse(req.url, true).query;

  //query database using params
  User.find({userId:params.userId})...

}
```

This will parse endpoints in the following format:

```
http://someApi.com?userId=MyId&param2=OtherParam...etc
```

Very minimal amount of code needed, you may have to slightly format the params to meet the mongoose query guidelines, but a framework really isn't necessary.